# Javascript to get the value of a checked radio field in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript

I need to get the values "trade" or "public" depending on which of these radio buttons is clicked:

```
<input name="customerType" type="radio" id="customerTypeTrade" class="filled-in valid" value="trade" required="">

<input name="customerType" type="radio" id="customerTypePublic" class="filled-in valid" value="public" checked="" required="">
```

Ive tried this but it returns 'undefined":

```
function() {
  var radioName = "customerType";
  var checked = {{Form Element}}.querySelector('[id="' + customerType + '"]:checked');
  return checked ? checked.value : undefined;
}
```

Comment: What's `{{Form Element}}`? Are you using angular?

Comment: customerType isn't a variable -- you need to use the variable `radioName` which has your string "customerType" -- plus go line by line with your JS (`console.log()` is a huge help) -- (1) does the function get called? (2) does "{Form Element}" exist? (3) can you target your radio buttons (regardless if checked or not)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way:

```js
var radio = document.querySelectorAll('[name=customerType]');
var checkedValue = document.querySelector('[name=customerType]:checked').value;
console.log(checkedValue);

function getValue(thatRad){
  checkedValue = thatRad.checked ? thatRad.value : undefined;
  console.log(checkedValue);
}
```

```html
<input name="customerType" type="radio" id="customerTypeTrade" class="filled-in valid" value="trade" required="" onchange="getValue(this)">

<input name="customerType" type="radio" id="customerTypePublic" class="filled-in valid" value="public" checked="" required="" onchange="getValue(this)">
```

Comment: I need this for Google Tag Manager. It says it needs a return value?

Comment: @chappers, then how do you attach the event handler function?

Comment: I dont know as i dont know anything about javascript thats why i post on here.

Comment: @chappers, as I am not quite clear about your requirements and specially how you use the returned value it is difficult to answer the question exactly to the point. I have updated the answer to `return` the value from function to print that in `console`.....thanks.

Comment: Sorted it:

    function() {
    var checked = document.querySelectorAll('[name=customerType]');
    var checkedValue = 
    document.querySelector('[name=customerType]:checked').value;

    if (checkedValue)
    return checkedValue;
    else 
    return "customer not selected";

}